# Subquery com mysql com duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Galera eu to tentando fazer uma subquery no where como condição para listar a media de horas trabalhadas maior que 20 e o titulo do codProj com 2 tabelas

A seguir o código:

```
SELECT projeto.codProj,trabalhaem.horas,AVG(trabalhaem.horas) AS media
FROM projeto INNER JOIN trabalhaem
ON projeto.codProj  = trabalhaem.codProj 
GROUP BY trabalhaem.horas
WHERE projeto.codProj in (SELECT titulo FROM projeto WHERE titulo = projeto.codProj) 
HAVING AVG(trabalhaem.horas) > 20;
```

tabela trabalhaEm:
        codEmp  ,
        codProj ,
        horas

tabela projeto: 
codProj ,
titulo,
codDepto ,

Comment: Me parece que dentro de sua subquery você está tentando se referir a um campo de sua tabela do SELECT externo. Neste caso atribua apelidos a cada ocorrência da tabela e utilize tais apelidos nas referências. No seu caso (SELECT titulo FROM projeto WHERE titulo = projeto.codProj) me parece meio estranho, existem dois campos (codProj e titulo) com o mesmo conteúdo na tabela projeto?

Comment: eu quero pegar o codProj e mostra apartir dele o titulo correspondente daquele código dizer verdade pra você to meio perdido em subquery por que a aula que a professora passo isso e eu não tava

Comment: Mas o que você deseja obter em sua subquery? Descreva em português para tentarmos entender. Que projetos são estes?

Comment: eu quero imprimir a media de horas trabalhadas maior que 20 com o codProj e pega esse codProj e mostrar apartir dele o titulo do projeto e tem que ser com uma subquery

Comment: Pelo que você descreveu não é necessária a utilização de subquery. Não faz sentido você colocar trabalhaem.horas e AVG(trabalhaem.horas) simultaneamente na lista de campos de seu SELECT e nem fazer GROUP BY por trabalhaem.horas. Novamente: descreva em português o que deseja obter e poste a definição das tabelas envolvidas.

Comment: então cara o exercicio pedi para fazer com query aninhada

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que consegui entender de seu problema, tente:

```
SELECT projeto.codProj, projeto.titulo, AVG(trabalhaem.horas)
FROM projeto INNER JOIN trabalhaem ON (projeto.codProj = trabalhaem.codProj)
HAVING (AVG(trabalhaem.horas) > 20)
GROUP BY projeto.codigo, projeto.titulo;
```